# How to make my own "const data" unmodifiable?

Tags: c++, reference, constants

I had a trouble with my own **`const`** attribute. I could not protect my const data completely because of functions. Functions can modify everything.

**`const reference`** is an awful thing because it requires an address; if it's an address of a const variable, most likely the variable data still can be changed or modified. My data is writeable. The parser cannot prevent (ignore) this kind of code because it's totally legal in C++.

```
scanf("%d", &const_var);
```

**How to lock my data and make my const data unmodifiable (or unwritable)?**

Comment: I can't make any sense of this. I think you need to communicate more clearly. Notably, there don't appear to be any references here.

Comment: Just don't use functions like `scanf` that pass parameters through `...`.

Comment: What do you mean by the word "avoidable"? As for scanf, it's a varargs function, so the compiler doesn't know that its args aren't const. You passed a ptr to a const int to it, and it changed it -- your fault for violating type safety.

Comment: **"avoidable"** means when executing the my script code, the parser may ignore the unexpected cases.

Comment: What parser? What script code? What do you mean by "ignore"? "unexpected cases"? None of any of that has much to do with the English language meaning of "avoidable".

Comment: And could you explain where I can use avoidable?

Comment: @xersi - Your use of the word "avoidable" is confusing. Please can you explain what you mean more clearly. Is the `scanf` case the only one where you have a problem?

Comment: Do you mean the word "avoidable"? Check an English language dictionary for how to use it. When you write "This code certainly is avoidable", that seems to mean that one can do something other than write such code. Meanwhile, you have two mentions of "my parser", but we know nothing about your parser or what the relevance is of what it does or does not ignore.

Comment: "In case my parser, functions can very easily change the const value. :(
Why? "-- You seem to be asking why your parser -- presumably a program you wrote -- is doing what it does. But there's no way for us to know, at all, why some parser of yours does something.

Comment: If your code has bugs, it will do things you don't expect it to do. You can try to find and fix the bugs. But you should also try to avoid things that are known to make it easier to write buggy code, such as passing things through `...`.

Comment: My data is readable and also is `**writable**`. So, it's main problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ is not a safe language. In C++, you can only protect yourself from accidents, not [*perfidy*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/perfidy). If a user wants to change something that they're not supposed to be able to change, it's as simple as this:

```
void SomeFunc(const Obj &dontChange)
{
  Obj &change = const_cast<Obj &>(dontChange);

  change.X = ...;
}
```

There is nothing you can do to protect yourself from a user who is *determined* to violate the contract between your code and theirs. You can only protect yourself from a user who accidentally tried to break the contract. You can't even protect private members of your class, as they can simply cast the type to something else and poke at the memory directly.

Your best bet is this: don't worry about it. If the user does the wrong thing with some variable, then any breakage that happens as a result is their fault.

Answer (score 3):

In this case...

```
scanf("%d", &foo); // Out of range!!!
```

...`foo` could indeed be modified, or pretty much anything else can happen. The compiler can't catch this because `scanf` uses old-fashion c `varargs` which allows any number of parameters, of any type to be passed, with no checking whatsoever. There is no attempt to ensure that the parameter passed is an address, let alone the address of an int, and certainly not the address of a non-const int.

For safer C++ code, avoid using `printf/sscanf` family of functions entirely.

Lint or some other source code checker could help here. I haven't tried it with this specific case.

Answer (score 1):

You can't protect yourself from such situations directly. If the constant is put inside writable memory, one may always acquire address of this constant and modify it one or another way. Remember though, that standard says, that modifying constant values is considered to have an undefined behavior.

If you want the constant to be unmodifyable, you can make a workaround and use a macro:

```
#define foo 100
```

This is a trick, because it will exchange all occurrences of `foo` in the source into `100`, however noone will be able to modify its value in the runtime (by definition, 100 is 100).

However, I would avoid using macros. You may use another workaround instead: define a function:

```
constexpr int FooValue()
{
    return 100;
}
```

Noone will be able to modify it either, but this solution allows you to embed such "constant" in class or namespace. If you use compiler, which can handle C++11, using constexpr will allow you to input this function everywhere, where you might have inserted a constant, for example:

```
int array[FooValue()];
```

Comment: `const int foo = 100` doesn't even have to live in memory (and certainly not in writable memory - on embedded systems `const` things end up in ROM)

Comment: No one will be able to reference it, by definition. But that doesn't address the OPs problem. They may still want to have const members in classes. Or even numerical constants which are namespaced (something that can't be accomplished with macros).

Comment: @Roddy "doesn't even have to live in memory" -- it does if you take its address, as the OP did.

Comment: @StoryTeller constexpr function solves that. Actually, I personally don't like macros, but I referenced them as one of available solutions.

Comment: @Spook, you added that after my comment :P

Comment: @StoryTeller I added that as a *response* to your comment. Improving answers is a common behavior on SO, isn't it?